# seleinum IDE WebDriver playback - IE driver - Not getting any of my actions recorded?

Tags: java, selenium, ide

I'm trying to use seleinum IDE to record scripts from the Internet Explorer browser.

I'm using this documentation: [WebDriver Playback in Selenium IDE is Here](http://blog.reallysimplethoughts.com/2013/02/18/webdriver-playback-in-selenium-ide-is-here/) which is linked directly in the seleinum IDE UI.

Here are the steps I followed:

- Install seleinum IDE plugin
- Activate WebDriver playback in Seleinum IDE options
- Restart Firefox and Seleinum IDE.
- Installed selenium-server-standalone-2.35.0.jar
- Installed IEDriverServer_Win32_2.35.3
- Ran `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.35.0.jar -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=IEDriverServer.exe -port 8099`
- Went to localhost:8099/wd/hub
- Create session using `internet explorer`
- IE window appears

At this point I expected that I would be able to go to the Internet Explorer window and have my commands captured by the Seleinum IDE, but that is not the case.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, selenium IDE only records in Firefox.

Comment: Yeah found that out the hard way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IDE only *records* in Firefox, but has the ability to *playback* into IE.

Your answer is therefore to *record* the **initial** test in Firefox, and use the server (as you are already), to play it back.

Comment: Yeah that doesn't work for me because this is a legacy app that doesn't work at all in firefox past the first screen that is all botched. BUT it's way better than nothing because I am able to successfully playback into IE!!!

Comment: I'll be using the Internet Explorer developer tools to find the elements and then write the actions by hand.